# Uncaught ReferenceError: show_pic is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:27

Tags: javascript, android, html, jquery-mobile

I am receiving the following error from eclipse (09-13 15:53:10.266: E/Web Console(24208): Uncaught ReferenceError: show_pic is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:27) when I attempt to call this function stored in main.js:

```
function show_pic() {
navigator.camera.getPicture(dump_pic, captureError, {
    quality : 50
});
}
```

Here is the html

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-     1.1.1.min.css" />
  <body>
  <div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="content">
  <div style="text-align:center;margin:20px;">
        <img id="cameraPic" src="" style="width:120px;height:120px;"></img>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">      
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onClick="show_pic()">Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar -->
    </div><!-- /footer -->
  </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Where is the function located? is it in the same page as the HTML shown above? if so... you should show where you actually placed the js function relative to the HTML markup.

Comment: @cube Read the question again.

Comment: @cube It is stored in main.js.

Comment: Is main.js in the same folder as the html page?

Comment: Hi! In your function `show_pic`, where are `dump_pic`, `captureErrorCan` defined? Can you only put `alert("ok");` in your function `show_pic` (in your file `main.js`) and see what it does. If not working, I suggest to put your js functions directly in your HTML file, between `<script>` tags, instead of `main.js`. Let me know if this works

Comment: They are also defined in main.js. They alert function produced the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I mofidied your code a bit. If I understood well, you want to display a picture that you take or that is in a specified location, when clicking on your `navbar` button `Two`.

According to what you want to do (displaying a picture that you are taking, or displaying a picture that is located in your device, etc), I defined 3 different functions `show_pic`, you may try them and use the one that fits your needs (2 of them are already in comments).

Also, while taking into account the previous suggestion in my comment, I included your function `show_pic()` directly inside the HTML code (in `script` tags) instead of `main.js`:

So here's the modified HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

        <!--  BASIC INCLUDES (TO CHANGE ACCORDING TO YOU) -->    

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.0.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>      
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>

        <!--  END - BASIC INCLUDES --> 

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

            var pictureSource;   // picture source
            var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 

            // Wait for Cordova to connect with the device
            //
            document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

            // Cordova is ready to be used!
            //
            function onDeviceReady() {
                pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
                destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
            }

            // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
            //
            function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
                // Uncomment to view the base64 encoded image data
                // console.log(imageData);

                // Get image handle
                //
                var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

                // Unhide image elements
                //
                smallImage.style.display = 'block';

                // Show the captured photo
                // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
                //
                smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
            }

            // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
            //
            function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
                // Uncomment to view the image file URI 
                // console.log(imageURI);

                // Get image handle
                //
                var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

                // Unhide image elements
                //
                largeImage.style.display = 'block';

                // Show the captured photo
                // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
                //
                largeImage.src = imageURI;
            }

// YOUR FUNCTIONS `show_pic()` --------------------------------------------------
            // YOUR FUNCTION `show_pic()`
            //
            function show_pic() {
                // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
                navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
                                        destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
            }

//            // YOUR FUNCTION `show_pic()`. Ex of use: onclick="show_pic(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);"
//            //
//            function show_pic() {
//                // Take picture using device camera, allow edit, and retrieve image as base64-encoded string  
//                navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20, allowEdit: true,
//                                            destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
//            }
//            
//            // YOUR FUNCTION `show_pic()`
//            //
//            function show_pic(source) {
//                // Retrieve image file location from specified source
//                navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
//                                            destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
//                                            sourceType: source });
//            }

// END - YOUR FUNCTION `show_pic()` ----------------------------------------------

            // Called if something bad happens.
            // 
            function onFail(message) {
                alert('Failed because: ' + message);
            }


            </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page">
            <div data-role="content">
                <div style="text-align:center;margin:20px;">
                    <img id="cameraPic" src="" style="width:120px;height:120px;"></img>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">      
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" onClick="show_pic()">Two</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /navbar -->
            </div><!-- /footer -->
        </div>
    </body><!-- <-- You forgot this missing DIV -->

</html>
```

---

**PS:**

- Since you're importing CSS / JS files from external web (http://code.jquery.com/), make sure that you've added the appropriate whitelist rule to your file `res/xml/cordova.xml`. I guess you may need to add something like `<access origin="http://code.jquery.com/" />` . Check this link for more information: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide .
- Also, since you're developing on Android, make sure that you modify your file `app/res/xml/` by adding: `<plugin name="Camera" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher" />`, and your manifest `app/AndroidManifest` by adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`
  .

---

Hope this helps. If you have any questions, you can ask me.

Also, for more useful information, you may wanna check the online doc: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#camera.getPicture

Comment: I will go through this. I probably should have mentioned that what i had worked at some point before. I need to do a lot more than just display an image and need to have the functions in a separate file.

My goal is to make it work (again) without the script in the HTML

Comment: Hey mate, I made some modification (argh, sorry I type very slow :S), check my post. Let me know if this works for you. Also, I forgot to mention this maybe important thing: I don't know if the camera feature is available for simulators or not... So I hope you won't have issues related to this.